# How to add a splash screen which should appear only on first launch of the app in windows phone using Phone Gap?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

How can i add a splash screen in windows phone using the PhoneGap which should appear on the first launch of the application, from the second launch it should not come. How to do it in PhoneGap some one answer my question please it would be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 0):

You can store a variable in your localStorage (accessible with js), in init of the app, check that variable and present the splash.

You don't need cordova related plugins etc, you can use localStorage in js directly in almost all platforms.

Here are some links to start:

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: But how to store and retrieve the variable in local storage in phone gap(Windows) i'm very new to it can you elaborate it please. @mentat

Comment: @Krrish: I edited my answer with some links. You don't need any phonegap/cordova libs to use localStorage.